# Determining multiples of 3 or 5 in python

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm relatively new to python and thus trying to set myself up running some simple algorithms. Here's the first problem from project euler, although there are other solutions available to the same problem in python, but I've tried a different approach.

In crux the idea is to find the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 less than 1000. This is my code.

```
def main():

    num = input('Insert number:')
    output = sumOfMultiples(num)
    print(output)


def sumOfMultiples(param):

    j = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(i, param):
        if (i % 3 ==0) or (i % 5 == 0) and (i % 15 != 0):
            j = j + i
    return j

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the error that I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Soumasish/PycharmProjects/MultiplesOf3And5/Main.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Soumasish/PycharmProjects/MultiplesOf3And5/Main.py", line 7, in main
    output = sumOfMultiples(num)
  File "/Users/Soumasish/PycharmProjects/MultiplesOf3And5/Main.py", line 15, in sumOfMultiples
    for i in range(i, param):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: add `param  = int(param)` in the beginning of `sumOfMultiples()`

Comment: As an aside, there is a mistake in your algorithm, and the PE solution will turn out to be incorrect. You're ignoring the multiples of 15, when in fact, you shouldn't.

Comment: your algorithm is `inefficient`!!it can be calculated in a single line

Comment: @rock321987 can you please elaborate as to how you can make the algorithm more efficient.

Comment: @shadow the multiples of 3 and 5 are ignored by design.

Comment: you can calculate the sum directly..upto `1000` there will be `floor(1000/3) = (let it be x)` numbers divisible by `3`, `floor(1000/5) = y` numbers divisible by `5` and `floor(1000/15) = z` numbers divisible by 15..

so the total `sum = (3 * x * (x + 1)) / 2 + (5 * y * (y + 1)) / 2 - (15 * z * (z + 1)) / 2`

Comment: @Clockwork - I'm not sure what you mean by that. PE-Q1 is about the sum of numbers that are divisible by 3 OR 5, but at the same time shouldn't ignore those that are divisible by 3 AND 5. Surprisingly, due to the order that your if condition is evaluated, the output is correct - 233168. However, the intended algorithm is incorrect, which would output - 200003. The reason that rock321987 subtracts multiples of 15 once, is because his algorithm implicitly ends up summing them twice, so he's compensating for that.

Comment: just look at the range..it is `below` i.e `not` including that number..so decrement `n` by 1..so it will be `999/3` like that

Comment: @rock321987 you do not require the divisible by 15 check in my opinion.

Comment: @user2963623 :it is required because while checking for `3` and `5` we will get multiples of `15` that are repeated `twice`..so it is required to subtract multiples of `15`

Comment: @rock321987 - But the for loop won't iterate over the same number twice. Also the conditional statement in your code makes the divisible by 15 check redundant. You have to put `if ((i % 3 ==0) or (i % 5 == 0)) and (i % 15 != 0):` You can check this with an example

Comment: @user2963623 : i think you have misinterprated my comment..i had written two comments..it was about my approach which was directly using formula..i am directly computing the answer without any loop..`yes` there is no need to check for the condition in the loop for divisibility of `15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your input as an int:

```
def main():
    num = int(input('Insert number:'))
    output = sumOfMultiples(num)
    print(output)
```

Furthermore, you can reduce your second method as follows. I checked and it still gives the correct answer:

```
def sumOfMultiples(param):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(param):
        if (i % 3 ==0) or (i % 5 == 0):
            sum += i
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with types, when you take an input in with:

```
num = input('Insert number:')
```

`num` is a string type. You can see this if you use `type(num)`. Then later you try to take a modulo with `num` and the modulo is not a defined operation with a string.

If you make the type correct the problem will go away:

```
num_str = input('Insert number:')
output = sumOfMultiples(int(num_str)) #this makes the input string an int first
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking each number by dividing it by 5 and 3 we can easily do it in O(1) with formula.

```
n=int(input())
a=(n-1)/3
b=(n-1)/5
c=(n-1)/15
ans=(3*a*(a+1)/2)+(5*b*(b+1)/2)-(15*c*(c+1)/2)
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input("enter the number : "))
lt = []
for i in range(num):
  if (i%3==0 or i%5==0):
     lt.append(i)
sum_of_lt=sum(lt)
print(sum_of_lt)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. This is especially important when answering old questions (this one is nearly 8 years old) with existing answers. See [answer].